# make inline result from array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array as bellow :

First array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => one
                    [number] => 051
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => two
                    [number] => 052
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => three
                    [number] => 053
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => four
                    [number] => 061
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => five
                    [number] => 062
                )

        )

)
```

I want to make output from first array above

```
[0] => 051, 052, 053.
[1] => 061, 062.

    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => book
                    [number] => 41
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => pencil
                    [number] => 42
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => eraser
            [number] => 71
        )

)
```

I want to make output from second array above

```
[0] => 41, 42.
[1] => 71.
```

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I wonder how a question showing no effort gets an upvote?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a try like this way with two `foreach()` loop.

```
$numbers = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $num = [];
    foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
       $num[] = $v2['number']; 
    }
     $numbers[$k] = implode(',',$num).'.';
}

print_r($numbers);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/mEeO7

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
$arr = Array (
    Array (
            Array (
                    "name" => "one",
                    "number" => "051"
                ),
            Array  (
                    "name" => "two",
                    "number" => "052"
                ),
            Array (
                    "name" => "three",
                    "number" => "053"
                )
        ),

    Array (
            Array (
                    "name" => "four",
                    "number" => "061"
                ),
            Array  (
                    "name" => "five",
                    "number" => "062"
                )
        )
);

foreach ($arr as $k => $s_arr) {
    echo "[" . $k . "] => ";
    foreach ($s_arr as $k2 => $v2) {
        echo $v2["number"] . " ";
    }

    echo "\n";
}
```