# how to display selected from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array in which two arrays have multiple array and one has single value which are as below:

```
    $array([0] => array(
    [0] => array(
        ['name'] => 'one',
        ['number'] => 051
    ),
    [1] => array(
        ['name'] => 'two',
        ['number'] => 052
    )
),
[1] => array(
    ['name'] => 'three',
    ['number'] => 053
),
[2] => array(
    [0] => array(
        ['name'] => 'four',
        ['number'] => 054
    ),
    [1] => array(
        ['name'] => 'six',
        ['number'] => 055
    )

)
```

From above array, how can I get result :

```
[0] = 051, 052.
[1] = 053.
[2] = 054, 055.
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: What language are you coding in, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: base on question [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560311/make-inline-result-from-array-value, I try to make solution $numbers = [];
 foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  $num = [];
  foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
     $num[] = $v2['number']; 
  }
   $numbers[$k] = implode(',',$num).'.';
 }

 print_r($numbers); but I have error on array[1] result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
$var = array(
        array(
            array(
                'name' => 'one',
                'number' => '051'
            ),
            array(
                'name' => 'two',
                'number' => '052'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'three',
            'number' => '053'
        ),
        array(
            array(
                'name' => 'four',
                'number' => '054'
            ), array(
                'name' => 'six',
                'number' => '055'
            )
            ));
    $numbers = [];
    foreach ($var as $k => $v) {
        $num = [];
            if(isset($v['number'])){
                $num[] = $v['number'];
            }
            foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                if(isset($v2['number'])){
                $num[] = $v2['number'];
                }
            }

        $numbers[$k] = implode(',', $num) . '.';
    }
```